# Cuspidal cubic in characteristic 3 with no inflection points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, plane-curves, positive-characteristic

Fix an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $3$. Consider a curve in $\mathbb{P}^2_{k}$ given by $$xy^2+yz^2+zx^2=0.$$
It seems to be a cubic with a cusp at $[1:1:1]$, whose Hessian $(x+y+z)^3$ meets it only at the cusp. Hence this cubic has no inflection point.

On the other hand, e.g. Appendix A of Silverman's *The Arithmetic of Elliptic curves* shows that every cuspidal cubic in $\mathbb{P}^2_{k}$ is projectively equivalent to $x^3=y^2 z$, so every point should be an iflection point.

What am I missing here? If I got Silverman wrong, and there is more than one cuspidal cubic on $\mathbb{P}^2_{k}$, could you give some reference where these cubics are classified? Also, do similar pathologies occur in characteristic two?

**EDIT:** After some computation, I arrived to a following conclusion: *a cubic $C\subseteq \mathbb{P}^{2}_{k}$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ has an inflection point, unless $\mathrm{char} k=3$ and $C$ is projectively equivalent to the above curve*. Therefore, I would like to ask now:

1. Is there any reference for this fact?
2. It is known (see e.g. Hartshorne's Example 6.11.4) that for a cuspidal cubic $C=\{y^3=x^2z\}$, we have $\mathrm{Pic}^0(C^{\mathrm{reg}})\cong\mathbb{G}_{a}$ as group schemes. Is there an analogous way to define a group structure on the smooth locus of the above curve? (Clearly, $\mathbb{G}_{a}$ won't work since $3p\neq 0$ for every point $p$, but maybe $C^{\mathrm{reg}}$ is still a torsor over something?)

Comment: Unless I've misread something, the result in Appendix A of Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* only applies to cubic curves in Weierstrass form, but your curve is not in Weierstrass form, so there's no contradiction.

Comment: You are right: and to get Weierstrass form, I need an inflection point, but my curve doesn't have one. So my question now becomes more like a reference request. Thank you!